# viewDidLoad and self.traitCollection undefined

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitraitcollection

I'm seeing times when self.traitCollection is undefined in viewDidLoad:

If I do the following simple presentation - the traits are NOT set (in viewDidLoad:)

```
TableViewController* vc = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However, if I use UIModalPresentationCurrentContext the traits ARE set (in viewDidLoad:)

Stranger still - if I insert a navigation controller as follows, the traits ARE set (in viewDidLoad: even with FullScreen presentation mode)

```
TableViewController* vc = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Obviously my 'solution' is to use CurrentContext - but I'm not clear whether this is a bug or a gap in my understanding. Any pointers would be most welcome.

I'm using iOS 8.3

Thanks

Comment: A note for people interested in an answer: this question has been answered in the Apple Developer Forums https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7854